# How to enable multiple action result set in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, sql-server-mars

I already added MARS_Connection=yes to my connection string to enable MARS or multiple action result sets. i'm using sql server 2000 and php 5.2 with PDO

This is my connection string

```
"odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydatabase;MARS_Connection=yes"
```

This is the error i got

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt
>   (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017264 ? The 3 score answer looks quite good?

Answer (score 0):

`MARS` is only available from SQL Server 2005 onwards:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109(SQL.90).aspx